# Сложность выполнения IEnumerable.First() с предикатом равна O(n)?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, коллекции, структуры-данных

В сети есть статьи, где обсуждаются алгоритмические сложности различных команд LINQ, но что-то ничего про сложность `IEnumerable.First()` **с предикатом** я не смог найти. Она ведь равна **O(n)**?

Comment: Ну давайте вместе подумаем, вот у вас есть неупорядоченный массив или двусвязный список не важно, там есть элементы [3,2,3,4,5] вы передаете предикат `(x => x == 100500 )` как по вашему сколько должна сделать итераций функция что бы **не найти** искомый вам элемент? Это и будет ответ на вопрос сколько сделает итераций функция в худшем случае.

Comment: Можно [здесь](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) своими глазами посмотреть.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, нужно 5 итераций.

Comment: @AdamShakhabov и следовательно у нас асимптотическая сложность будет O(n)